# $.mobile.changePage($("") always load changed web page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a hard time getting $.mobile.changePage() working properly.
things like:
i have a page call "report outage" and there is a add button on it.
when i click add button, the app will go to another page named "new outage",
and then i will enter some information and submit it.
afer that i go back the  "report outage" again, and click the add button, but 
every time i got the revised page other than the original page.
i am using the $.mobile.changePage() to transfer "report outage" to "new outage".

any suggestion will be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `reloadPage` option to `true` for the `$.mobile.changePage()` method. This will only work if you are loading an external page, not an internal one (multi-page template).

For Example:

```
$.mobile.changePage("some-external-page.html", {
    reloadPage : true
});
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: thanks for quick response but it is a internal one then how can i cope with it. thanks buddy.

Comment: @user1712576 That would take some custom code. You'd have to save the original version of the page when `document.ready` (or something similar) fires so that when you navigate away from the page you can delete it and replace it with a copy of the original. I'd recommend moving to a single-page template where each pseudo-page is in its own HTML document, so you can get this functionality without any custom code.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage($("newoutagePage.html"), {
   reloadPage : true
  });

Comment: but when i click the button, it didn't switch to page should add like:

Comment: $.mobile.changePage($("./newoutagePage.html"), { reloadPage : true });

Comment: Don't place the URL string in a jQuery object, just pass `.changePage()` a string as the first argument. Like so: `$.mobile.changePage("./newoutagePage.html", { reloadPage : true });`

Comment: but i got another problem i found out that some javascript for this page doesn't work any more. how can i solve that.

Comment: You are probably running your JS code on `document.ready` but you need to swap to `pseudo-page.pageinit`. `pageinit` fires when a page is added to the DOM, so it's like `document.ready` for jQuery Mobile pseudo-pages, see the documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html